# How to get Strings to show up in a list?

Tags: java, string, swing, draw

EDIT: Updated the code but it just overwrites the drawString everytime now.

I can't get the input from the drawString to show up 15px lower everytime you say something in the Textfield. How can I get all the Strings you type to show up underneath eatchother?

Thanks in advance (Im new to JAVA)..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class paneel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField invoer;
private JButton knop;
//private String item1;
private item item;
int y = 50;

public paneel() {
    setLayout(null);

    item = new item();
    //item1 = "";
    item.setItem("");

    invoer = new JTextField(10);
    invoer.setBounds(50, 25, 150, 20);

    knop = new JButton("Voeg toe");
    knop.addActionListener(new invoerVakHandler());
    knop.setBounds(225, 25, 125, 20);

    add(invoer);        add(knop);
}

class invoerVakHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String item1 = invoer.getText();

        invoer.setText("");

        item.setItem(item1);

        repaint();
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15);
    g.setFont(font);

    y += 35;

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(50, 75, 300, 400);

    g.drawString(String.format("- %s", item.getItem()), 100, y);
}
}
```

Comment: Because your `y` is a local variable, `y -= 15` is rather strange, you probably need an instance variable for `y`, for more informations, see this: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html (for example)

Comment: can you post testable example?

Comment: *"How to get Strings to show up in a list?"* Use a `JList` with [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). Display the list in a `JScrollPane` in a `JPanel` with a suitable layout/constraint. When adding a new `String`, call `DefaultListModel.addElement(Object)`. Easy, and a lot more robust than custom painting. As an aside: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @FastSnail *"testable example"* note that `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Within your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, you are  currently using a local variable instead of a class instance variable for `y`. With your current implementation, every single time `paintComponent` is called, a new local variable `y` is created (and deleted once `paintComponent` is complete), with each time the variable being set to 120, then drawn at 135px for every string.

You need to change y to an instance variable, so the variable remains in memory.

Just under `public class paneel {`, add your definition of `y` there, so it is available for every method within the instance of `paneel`.

So a snippet sample code could be:

```
public class paneel {
    int y = 120;
...
...

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //adding 15 to the instance of y.
    //Since y is defined as a class member, and not a local variable, the update to y will remain in memory.
    y += 15;

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(50, 75, 300, 400);

    g.drawString(String.format("- %s", item.getItem()), 100, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get all the Strings you type to show up underneath eatchother?

You need to repaint all the `String`s every time the `paintComponent(...)` method is invoked.

So this means you need to keep an ArrayList of all the strings you want to paint. Then in the paintComponent(...) method you iterate through the List and paint each string while increment the y offset every iteration.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `DrawOnComponent` example contains a working example of this approach. The example paints Rectangles, but the concept is the same for a String.